# How to increment count in database using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Initially count is 0 in database. i need to update count every time whenever request comes.

**Update Query**

Here count is initially 0.

**suppose int count=10;
query.setParameter("count",count);
it will update only one time
the output is 11.next time same query update same output 11 will come.but i need 12 is the output.**

```
String hql = "Update User f set f.count =:count + 1 where f.userId =:userId";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        //query.setParameter("count", count);
        result = query.executeUpdate();
```

count is not updated. looking positive replay.

Thank you..!

Comment: This snippet will not run. ":count" parameter is never set to the query object.

Comment: @SudoRahul i added query.setParameter("count",count); but it's not updated

Comment: And did you pass the older count value?

Comment: @SudoRahul yes.i don't want setParamter based on db count it will increment 1 every time

Comment: Then the answer by 'ruslanys' should be the one you should check out.

Comment: @SudoRahul thank you so much it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try?

```
"Update User f set f.count=(f.count + 1) where f.userId =:userId";
```